# Get data from database inside classes in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop, pdo

How can I get data from my database inside classes?

I have a `users` table in my database and I want to access this data in a object oriented way. This means I don't want to write queries all the time in my code, instead i want to get this data by lets say `$Users->getUserById(2)->getName();`

But the problem is that i can't get my database connection up in these classes.

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=ipofdatabase;dbname=nameofdatabase", "username", "password", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));

class Users {
    public function usersList() {
        $db_users = $pdo->query("SELECT id, username, mail FROM users");
        $users = array();

        foreach ($db_users as $u) {
            $users[] = array(
                'id' => $u['id'],
                'username' => $u['username'],
                'mail' => $u['mail']
            );
        }
    }

    public function getUserById($id) {
        return new User($id);
    }
}
```

I want that `$Users->usersList()` outputs an array with all the data but instead I get an error that the variable $pdo in line 3 is undefined.

> Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in C:\apache\docs\Users.php on line 6

Should I establish a database connection in every single class? Wouldn't this be a performance hit?

Comment: You forgot to pass `$pdo` as argument to `usersList()`,  if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a `__construct` function to get to PDO. You declare the `$pdo` variable **outside** of the class. The class has access to what's **inside** it.

```
class Foo
{
    protected $pdo; # here we define PDO as part of the class scope.

    public function __construct()
    {
        # we then assign $pdo to be a PDO instance
        $this->pdo = new \PDO('mysql:hostname=localhost;dbname=foobar', 'user', 'pass');
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        # we then use the $pdo var using $this->pdo
        $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `table`');
        # etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked and easy to understand, thanks! But is this a performance hit? In my understanding, the database connection gets established only at the beginning when I write `$Users= new Users();`, so it wouldn't be a performance hit. Is this correct?

Comment: @K.Miller yeah, they'll be next to no performance issue. You can, if you'd prefer, create a DB-specific class and inject that into the constructor, but meh - if you're code base isn't big, don't worry about it

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. Create a model to store the 'User' data. Then the UserHandler can load and keep track of these models.

Additionally, a reference to the DH could be passed to the UserHandler construct to preserve connection from another part of your script.

```
<?php 

class User{
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $mail;

    public function __construct( $sArg_Id = "", $sArg_UserName = "", $sArg_Mail = "" ) {        
        $this->id = (int)$sArg_Id;
        $this->username = $sArg_UserName;
        $this->mail = $sArg_Mail;
    }
}


class UserHandler {

    // hold references to our user objects
    public $aUsers = array();

    // hold a ref to DataHandler     
    public $oDH = null;
    private $bDHInit = false;


    public function __construct( &$oArg_DH = null ) {

        // if reference passed, and if not already init
        if($oArg_DH && !$this->bDHInit){
            $this->oDH = $oArg_DH;
            $this->bDHInit = true;
        }
    }

    public function usersList() {

        $this->InitDH();

        $db_users = $this->oDH->query("SELECT id, username, mail FROM users");

        // add a new user object to aUsers array
        foreach ($db_users as $u) {
            $this->aUsers[$u['id']] = new User($u['id'], $u['username'], $u['mail']);
        }
    }

    public function getUserById($id) {

        if(isset($this->aUsers[$id])){
            return $this->aUsers[$id];
        }else{

            // load user id, or return new user object with id
            // return new User($id);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function InitDH(){
        // I would also create a DataHandler class to wrap some of the PDO methods
        if(!$this->bDHInit){

            $this->oDH = new PDO(
                "mysql:host=ipofdatabase;dbname=nameofdatabase", 
                "username", 
                "password", 
                array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));

            $this->bDHInit = true;
        }
    }
}
```